# Android: mobile coverage analyzer that takes all 4G and 3G providers into account

Tags: android

Commuting by train in rural Germany, I am looking for a provider that can give me usable data connections throughout my trip. So I'll have to consider 3G and 4G coverage from four different operators. I would be ok with restricting my Android data setup to only consider 3G networks, if that reduces pauses during handovers. My main goal is continuous coverage in any one network.

I'm not too keen, however, on buying four throwaway SIM cards and making eight roundtrips while staring at the signal strength indicator.

Is there any software I can install on an Android device that takes measurements of network communication across *all* networks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the data on [OpenSignal](http://opensignal.com/) who have good coverage maps of a lot of areas and you can also get their [App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.staircase3.opensignal) which will allow you to record the signal strength rather than staring at the screen. Plus if you were to get the four throwaway SIMs then given that the rails are *mostly* very close to each other and *most* rail trips are routed the same way in each direction then just two round trips, (one SIM per **one-way** trip), should gather the data you need.

### App Screen

[image: App Screen]

### [Web Site](http://opensignal.com/)

[image: Web Page]

Comment: Wow, I lost track of this question for a loooong time, sorry ;-) I found the data provided by OpenSignal t be helpful but not quite perfect. There does not seem to be a better alternative, however. What I did find out is that it takes quite a few measurements to get meaningful results in order to average out local effects (people, weather etc.) given that mobile devices have very restricted antennas.